# Unknown error after using tilemap in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

sorry for my English. I have a problem, I started studying unity and created a small location using tilemap, enemies, inventory. Then I wanted to expand my map and started drawing it, but this leads to an unknown error.

Before that, I drew the location in the old version of the editor 2020, then it will continue in the new 2022. Could there be a problem with that? I imported only the joystick and cinemachine from the packages. Here is a line from the report before "crash". It's different every time

```
Asset Pipeline Refresh (id=b8347e7b8d94ac34aa895b7b52ac7864): Total: 0.040 seconds - Initiated by StopAssetImportingV2(NoUpdateAssetOptions)

Crash!!!

SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath: 'C:/Program Files/Unity/Hub/Editor/2022.3.0f1/Editor/Data/Mono;.;C:\Game;C:\Game\Library\BurstCache\JIT;C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.0f1\Editor;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;', symOptions: 534, UserName: 'Tsumi'
OS-Version: 6.3.0
```